# Как поменять цвет у значения переменной JS и вывести?

Tags: javascript, html

```
if (programmingTimePlan > 0) {
    document.getElementById("programmingTimePlan").innerHTML = programmingTimePlan; //вывод перевыполненного плана
} else if (programmingTimePlan == 0) {
    document.getElementById("programmingTimePlan").innerHTML = programmingTimePlan; //вывод выполненного плана
} else {
    document.getElementById("programmingTimePlan").innerHTML = programmingTimePlan; //вывод не выполненного плана
}
```

Переменная `programmingTimePlan` показывает выполнен ли план. Если число положительное, то мне нужно вывести "+" и число `programmingTimePlan` зеленого цвета. Если равен нулю, то просто число. А если меньше 0, то "-" и число `programmingTimePlan` красного цвета. Как поменять цвет и прибавить знак "+" или "-"?

```
<b>За всё время</b>: <span id="programmingTime"></span> XP (<i><span id="programmingTimePlan"></span></i>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (programmingTimePlan > 0) {
    document.getElementById("programmingTimePlan").innerHTML = '<span style="color:green;">+' + programmingTimePlan + '</span>'; //вывод перевыполненного плана
} else if (programmingTimePlan == 0) {
    document.getElementById("programmingTimePlan").innerHTML = programmingTimePlan; //вывод выполненного плана
} else {
    document.getElementById("programmingTimePlan").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red;">' + programmingTimePlan + '</span>'; //вывод не выполненного плана
}
```

Также для изменения цвета можете оперировать классами или стилями самого тега с id `programmingTimePlan`.